# How do I accept both integer and string inputs in JOptionPane?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm creating a java program where the user has to guess between 1 to 10, in which if they're wrong it'll loop. I need it so they can also input String words into it.

`I haven't tried anything yet since I am still a beginner in java

Here's the code

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //int numcor;

    while (true) {
      int numcor = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 1 to          10: "));
      //numcor = input.nextInt();
      if (numcor == 5) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct number!");
        break;
      } else if (input == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye!");
        break;
      } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try Again");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The user can enter either numbers or strings when you call method [showInputDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.lang.Object)). Your question is not clear to me. In any case, did you try Googling for [java swing number guessing game](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+number+guessing+game) to see how others have done it?

Comment: The `Scanner` is redundant, but there is nothing essentially wrong with your code, barring lack of input sanitization and its being uninteresting because of the hardcoded value of 5

Comment: @abra Regardless what an application is asking for, users can always input wrong or meaningless stuff. The application has to be made resilient, either by guiding the user (only allow number characters for numbers) or be prepared to digest anything.

Comment: Try to use this in your code and your game will be more interesting: `int randVal = (int)(1 + Math.random() * 10);`

Comment: Why does everybody suggest `Math.random()` for generating random int in a range? There are much, much simpler ways - 1) `rnd.nextInt(10) + 1` or 2) `rnd.nextInt(1, 11)` on java 17+.

Comment: Because that requires imports and the OP is a beginner. My purpose was to provide code that can slot in easily

Comment: @g00se This was more of a general question, because 9 out of 10 people I see suggest this, which is mindblowing (IMO). Ok, no imports might be easier, but OP is already using imports in his code, so...

Comment: Yes, I tend to agree about the general point. But as for ease of slotting in, I would have had to say "You need to import java.util.Random" though I could have used the f.q. package name in the code, but again, that would be a little unnatural and might be the beginning of odd habits ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just open a dialog where the user can input some characters. As soon as the user is done, your program starts interpreting the entered characters.

If it can be parsed as an integer, treat it as in integer.
Otherwise treat it as text and do the needful.

In code this could look like:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 1 to 10: ");
try {
    int numcor = Integer.parseInt(input);
    // treat the number
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // treat input as text
}
```